# I am trying to write a code but facing a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Please check the code out

Tags: java

So I am trying to take multiple inputs.
here is the question:-
Given two strings of equal length, you have to tell whether they both strings are identical.

Two strings S1 and S2 are said to be identical, if any of the permutation of string S1 is equal to the string S2. See Sample explanation for more details.

Input :
First line, contains an intger 'T' denoting no. of test cases.
Each test consists of a single line, containing two space separated strings S1 and S2 of equal length.

Output:

For each test case, if any of the permutation of string S1 is equal to the string S2 print YES else print NO.

Constraints:

1<= T <=100

1<= |S1| = |S2| <= 10^5

String is made up of lower case letters only.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        String parts[]=new String[10];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no of inputs");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int j=n;
        for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter string");
            String s=sc.next();
            int in=s.indexOf(" ");
            String s1=s.substring(0,in);
            String s2=s.substring(in+1);
            boolean status = true;  
            if (s1.length() != s2.length()) 
            {  
                status = false;
            } 
            else 
            {  
                char[] ArrayS1 = s1.toCharArray();  
                char[] ArrayS2 = s2.toCharArray();  
                Arrays.sort(ArrayS1);  
                Arrays.sort(ArrayS2);  
                status = Arrays.equals(ArrayS1, ArrayS2);  
            }  
            if (status==true) 
            {  
                System.out.println(s1 + " and " + s2 + " are anagrams");  
            }    
            else 
            {  
                System.out.println(s1 + " and " + s2 + " are not anagrams");  
            }  
    }  
    }
}
```

[image: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException] the error
[image: where the issue persists]   issue

Comment: Which line is the error on? Please put a comment or mark it in some way.

Comment: `String s=sc.next();` - `s` will never contain a space, so `int in=s.indexOf(" ");` is `-1`. Try `sc.nextLine();`

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @Elliott

Comment: When you try `nextLine()` be aware of this: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/5221149)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the statement

```
String s = sc.next();
```

That will never consume a token with a space (because white space is the delimiter). Change it to

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

And then

```
int in = s.indexOf(" ");
```

will work (but only if the input contains a space); so you should still test it is not `-1` yourself.

```
if (in >= 0) {
    String s1 /* ... */
}
```

Also,

```
int n=sc.nextInt();
```

will leave trailing newlines (and skip your next input) using `nextLine()` so consume that too.

```
int n=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // <-- skip trailing new line.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows:

```
System.out.print("Enter no of inputs: ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter no of inputs: 3
Enter string: Hello Hi
Hello and Hi are not anagrams
Enter string:
```

I recommend you go through [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for a better understanding of `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("Enter string");
sc.nextLine();
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It print YES and NO according to your requirement.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Main Class
public class ThreadGroupDemo implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String parts[] = new String[10];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no of inputs");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int j = n;

        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter string");
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            int in = s.indexOf(" ");
            String s1 = s.substring(0, in);
            String s2 = s.substring(in + 1);
            boolean status = true;
            if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
                status = false;
            } else {
                char[] ArrayS1 = s1.toCharArray();
                char[] ArrayS2 = s2.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(ArrayS1);
                Arrays.sort(ArrayS2);
                status = Arrays.equals(ArrayS1, ArrayS2);
            }
            if (status == true) {
                System.out.println("YES");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.